# Porque no puedo ver una imagen en mi aplicación?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, imagen, android-layout, interfaz-gráfica

estoy creando una aplicación en Android studio para un proyecto escolar (soy nuevo en tema de programación), agregué una splash screen a la aplicación y funcionó, luego intenté crear una pantalla de login, agregué 2 imagenes y una imagen button, pero cuándo ejecuté la aplicación en teléfono se veía solamente blanco.

Eliminé todo y solamente agregué un texto y ese si se veía, pero reemplazando el texto con una imagen se volvía a quedar en blanco la pantalla.
De antemano gracias.

Código del activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="571dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Código del activity.kt:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity

class RegisterActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)
    }
}
```

Codigo del AndroidManifest de las activitys:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ejemplo" />
```